# C# - Handle BulkInsert when exception occurs?

Tags: c#, exception, bulkinsert, goto

I have code like so:

```
public void InsertData() {
    ...
    
    try {
        context.BulkInsert(Table1Data);
        context.BulkInsert(Table2Data);
        context.BulkInsert(Table3Data);
        context.BulkInsert(Table4Data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Data failed to insert");
    }
}
```

Let's say that an exception occurs on the insert of "Table2Data". If so, then the database has already inserted "Table1Data" but because of the exception now won't insert "Table3Data" or "Table4Data".

Regardless of "Table2Data" working or not, I need "Table3Data" and "Table4Data" inserted.

What would be the best way to handle this? Can I add something like a goto statement in my exception so that it will continue on with the inserts? I am mainly hoping to avoid putting each BulkInsert into its own try catch.

Comment: You can't avoid putting each of them in its own handler. You can, however, refactor the error handling -- make your `InsertData` method take the `table` as a parameter, then call it four times (or use `foreach` and a collection). (And make the error handling you do have a little better than a generic console writeline, obviously.)

Comment: *I am mainly hoping to avoid putting each BulkInsert into its own try catch.* - why? If it's to save a few hundred characters, I'd point out that you then had to write 1000 characters question to ask about how to do it, so you've already worn your fingers out more :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a code like so:

```
public void InsertData() {
    ...
    
    foreach(var x in new[]{Table1Data,Table2Data,Table3Data,Table4Data})
      try {
        context.BulkInsert(x);
      }
      catch {
        Console.WriteLine("Data failed to insert");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably pass tabledata(s) from outside as a parameter, or use a finally block in which based on an if condition of your try code fail/pass, make recursive calls?